# connection error 08001:[unixODBC][Teradata][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[DBCName]} in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, teradata

I am facing error while fetch data from Teradata DB using below code all configuration is okay DB is accessible via terminal, ODBC is installed on ubuntu server

```
$sDriver = 'Teradata';
$sDBCName = 'IP';
$sDatabase = 'DB_NAME';
$sDSN = "Driver={$sDriver};DBCName={$sDBCName};Database={$sDatabase};";
$connection = odbc_connect("Teradata DSN", "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD");
if($connection) {
     do some thing
   } else {
       echo "connection error " . odbc_error() . ":" . odbc_errormsg()
}
```

So below is the error

```
connection error 08001:[unixODBC][Teradata][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[DBCName]}
```

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with how you "anonymized" the code, but as written you are building  a connection string which you don't use for the connection.

Comment: Do you have a DSN named "IP"?

Comment: @Andrew,  yes using IP and DSN as well